# c#: cannot get user's active directory groups

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, ldap, c#-3.0

my code works in my local computer, but keep getting error message after I deployed to dev server.

Error Message:

```
    System.ArgumentException: The (&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(|(userPrincipalName=)(distinguishedName=)(name=))) search filter is invalid.
       at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext()
       at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_InnerList()
       at System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.get_Count()
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRefHelper(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate, Boolean useSidHistory)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRef(Type principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime referenceDate)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String identityValue, DateTime refDate)
       at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext context, String identityValue)
       at CLAdmin.Web.Infrastructure.Helpers.ADHelper.GetUserGroups(String userName)
```

Here's my code:

```
    public List<string> GetUserGroups(string userName)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, _ADDomain))
            {
                var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, userName);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    //var groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
                    var groups = user.GetGroups();

                    foreach (Principal p in groups)
                    {
                        if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                        {
                            result.Add(p.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("An error happened in GetUserGroups", ex);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the `FindByIdentity` method you are using works is by (eventually, somewhere down the call chain) building the query based on the username you pass in.

Given that exception shows empty strings in the filter clauses, I would suspect that the username you are passing in is either null or empty.  Add a parameter check at the top of the method to verify that the userName parameter is not null or empty (I would recommend throwing an instance of `System.ArgumentException` or one of its descendants, and I bet you would see that exception instead of the one you described.

Answer (score 1):

Filters used in search requests must contain *assertions*. Constructs like `(attributeName=)` will not work, and as the error message indicates, are invalid.

Filters are either

- equality: `(attributeName=attributeValue)`
- substring: `(attributeName=attributeVa*)`
- present: `(attributeName=*)`

and some other types. For a discussion of filters, see:

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)